# How to connect client in a internet to the server

Tags: python, sockets, wan

I made a simple chat room. But I can't connect clients who joined through internet. I know I'm using local network to this program. But I researched how to connect my server to the internet. I used my Dynamic public IP and port forwarded using my router, but It didn't work. And I used ngrok, but it also didn't work. How can I solve this problem.

This is a part of my program.

```
IP_Address = 'IP'
Address = (IP_Address,PORT)

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(Address) # Bind IP address and Port to this socket.
```

When I used my public addressit shows this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Documents/Projects/Python/server.py", line 13, in <module>
server.bind(Address) # Bind IP address and Port to this socket.
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `server.bind(('',port))` or `server.bind(('0.0.0.0',port))`. Both mean "bind to all interfaces".

If you want to bind to a specific interface, use your local IP, not the public one.  Use `ipconfig` from the console to see your IP address.

On the router, forward the port to your local IP.  Clients on the internet connect to your public IP and port.

Comment: I used your method but it didn't work. I used my local IP in the server and port forwarded using the router. Server side is working well but when I used my public IP to client and try to connect to the server it didn't connect.

Comment: @VinuraYashohara Does your server have a firewall enabled?

Comment: I'm using Debian Linux. I didn't install any software firewall to my OS  and I try to up my server by disabling my router's firewall, but the result is still same as before.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this problem is using a Cloud Application Platform to run the server program.